# Three.js GridHelper: How to hide/show the grid?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am adding a plane and a grid using [Gridhelper](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Helpers/GridHelper) to my 3d scene:

```
// PLANE XY static
var gridplaneSize = 20;
var color = 0xFFDCBB;
var plGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(gridplaneSize, gridplaneSize);
var plMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color:color, ambient:color, side:THREE.DoubleSide, opacity:0.5, transparent:true, depthWrite: false } );
var planeMesh_xy = new THREE.Mesh(plGeometry, plMaterial);
planeMesh_xy.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
scene.add(planeMesh_xy);
planeMesh_xy.receiveShadow = true;
// GRID XY static
var gridstep = 1;
var gridcolor = 0xCCCCCC;
var gridHelper_xy = new THREE.GridHelper(gridplaneSize/2, gridstep);
gridHelper_xy.position = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
gridHelper_xy.setColors( new THREE.Color(gridcolor), new THREE.Color(gridcolor) );
scene.add(gridHelper_xy);
```

Then I would like to decide if the plane or the grid is visible.

This works for the plane:

```
planeMesh_xy.visible = false;
```

But *not* for the grid:

```
gridHelper_xy.visible = false; // not working
```

I also tried workarounds, not working:

```
gridHelper_xy.material.transparent = true;
gridHelper_xy.material.opacity = 0;
gridHelper_xy.parent.visible = false;
```

Can anyone tell me how to hide the grid then?

Comment: according to this issue https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1524 if you are on r71 this should work as all childs should inherit the flag.

Comment: have you tried `scene.remove(gridHelper_xy.name);`?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am on `r65`.
@SamyBencherif So I should do the remove-workaround? I remember this from another project with other objects.

Comment: @Matheretter I've never actually used three-js. My suggestion's more of a guess. What is `r65`?

Comment: r65 is the version number of three.js. I had problems with r68 throwing errors. I will try r71 now.

Comment: It works with r71 (THREE.WebGLRenderer 71). @gaitat: Thanks a lot! Post it as answer so that I can select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What should happen when you set the `visible` flag of an object is that all of its children should inherit the flag.

In r71 this should work out of the box (look at issue https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1524)

In r65 you would have to traverse your hierarchy setting the flag on all the sub-parts:

```
object.traverse ( function (child) {

    child.visible = false;

}
```